# Generating irrelevant links in my web site

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a .net based web application where I have used url rewriting.

I have used error reporting by email, and I am getting error messages about links that are not formed in my website so what exactly I supposed to do?

Comment: Is there any pattern to the URLs that are being reported? Can you add the UserAgent to the error report and see if it's some sort of automated bot attempting to find a vulnerability (for example I see a number of errors on my sites for random wordpress/phpbb admin/installer scripts, which are nothing to do with my site)

Answer (score 0):

Test the exception type and don't send them maybe?

Comment: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

inner exception: Input string was not in a correct format. this is what i get only

Comment: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Stack trace:
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext
context)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.product_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) i am geting this e

Comment: @Sumit: you should post extra information as an edit to your question.